# It is possible that I could user email address to get customer id from simPRO API?

Tags: php, oauth, google-sheets

Currently I am using the simPRO API, I have a customer sheet in my spreadsheet, while the currently there are some blanks in this sheet. 
I now have the company ID and part of the customerID. And for the customers I have their name and address, email. While in my opinion, name and address cannot be used to identify and could be duplicate, so the only way I think maybe i need to use email.
So is their a way that I could find the customer Id through email?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### According to the [SimPRO API CustomerHandler Docs](http://api.simpro.co/classes/CustomerHandler.html):

> ### CustomerSearchFields
>
> ```
> SearchFields(int $CompanyID, array $SearchTerms, int $Limit = 500, int $Offset = 0, string $SearchType = "AND") : array
> ```
>
> STATIC
>
> This function retrieve's a list of customers who's set of fields match
>   their associated values
>
> Uses\CustomerHandler::RetrieveList()
>
> #### Parameters
>
> $CompanyID
>
> `int`
>
> the Company ID. In single company builds, this is 0.
>
> $SearchTerms
>
> `array`
>
> An associative array of Search Fields[key] and their search terms
>   [value]
>
> $Limit = 500
>
> `int`
>
> the total number of clients to return (0 - 500)
>
> $Offset = 0
>
> `int`
>
> how many results to skip, before returning {@link $Limit}
>
> $SearchType = "AND"
>
> `string`
>
> Multiple SearchTerms to perform a 'AND' or 'OR' search (default 'AND')
>   SearchTerms can take keys of 'Address','Suburb', 'State', 'Postcode'
>   and 'Email'
>
> #### Returns
>
> `array`

... You could search for the clients using a POST request like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "method": "CustomerSearchFields",
  "params": {
    "CompanyID": 0,
    "SearchTerms": {
      "Email": "email@address.com"
    },
    "SearchType": "AND"
  }
}
```

You would then just need to extract the Customer ID from the results.

If there is any more than a single result though, you would need more criteria.